# can't see other database on mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, database, workbench

two computers installed mysql 5.5.25a which downloaded from the mysql official site. one is connecting to another's mysql server through MySql WorkBench,but can only see the 'test' database ,can't see others database for example the 'sakila' database.How can i fix it?

Comment: Are you sure that user:password you are using for connection has permissions to see / interact with databases on target computer?

Comment: both are user "root" and password is "sasa" what's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to manually import sakila/world/menagerie databases from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/index-other.html). Only these databases- `test, mysql, information_schema and performance_schema` would be present after installing MySQL.